# Add custom name to time_zone_select field in Rails form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

I want to add a custom name to a select field in my Rails form. The field is generated using the [time_zone_select](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_select) form option helper. I used `'name'=>'squad_cycle[start_time][0]'` with time_field and date_field form helpers and it worked, but this doesn't work with time_zone_select.

Below is my erb:

```
<%= f.date_field :start_date, 'name'=>'squad_cycle[start_date][0]' %>
<%= f.time_field :start_time, 'name'=>'squad_cycle[start_time][0]' %>
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, default: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' %>
```

HTML output:

```
<input name="squad_cycle[start_date][0]" type="date" id="squad_cycle_start_date">
<input name="squad_cycle[start_time][0]" type="time" id="squad_cycle_start_time">
<select name="squad_cycle[time_zone]" id="squad_cycle_time_zone">...</select>
```

Comment: Check http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-time_zone_select. `html_options` is the argument where you can give `name: 'your_custom_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your html options as follow:

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, { default: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' }, { name: 'my_custom_name' } %>
```

Read more at [APIDock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_select)